# What are the greater than and less than tags used for when wrapping

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and have seen code like the following:

```
  this._tags = <BehaviorSubject<Tag[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

What I can't seem to find is the use of "<>".

What is the purpose of wrapping BehaviorSubject and Tag[] in "<>"?

Comment: Typecasting. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called Type Assertion.
Using Type Assertion Typescript will convert one data type to another data type.

Example 
var anyvalue: any;
var stringValue =  anyvalue;

In the this example Typescript will convert anyvalue to string value.

```
this._tags = <BehaviorSubject<Tag[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

In this code your converting BehaviorSubject of any array type to BehaviorSubject of Tag array.

**Type Assertion vs. Type Casting**

Type assertions are purely a compile time and Type Casting will support run time.

Comment: Not only that - the tags are used for generic typing when it's positioned after another type! Think of `Promise<string>`.